# Are there zeros of $\zeta(s)-\zeta(2s)$ on $\Re(s)=1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am trying to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302273/zeros-of-prime-zeta-function) question on Math.SE which is asking if $P(s)$ has any zeros with $\Re(s)=1$, and if it were true that $\zeta(s)-\zeta(2s)$ had no zeros on $\Re(s)=1$ then I would be able to complete my proof that there is no "zero-like behavior" (i.e $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{P(z)}$=0 always).

Does anyone know of a proof that $\zeta(s)-\zeta(2s)$ is zero free?

Comment: the title says $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, the question says $\Re(s)=1$, which is it?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker fixed!

Comment: For instance you may start  checking [this paper](https://web.yonsei.ac.kr/haseo/p21-reprint.pdf)

Comment: @zeraouliarafik this is a fascinating paper, and it may take me a while to go all the way through it. Does it contain the result I am looking for?

Comment: @MiloMoses, I think it would be very useful to your problem , actually I ask  if Riemann zeta function injective at Re(s)=1 ? if yes you may start your proof by contradiction way you may come up to show whether the difference you have is zero free